# whats wrong with my query CAML

Tags: caml-query, caml

```
$caml = '<Where><AND><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" />
<Value Type="Text">Off-S</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" />
<Value Type="Text">Off</Value></Neq></AND></Where>'
```

I have this query, which doesn't return anything.
What I want is it to return all the items that are in the column `marking` that are not equal to `Off-S` and `Off`

Comment: Stop hand writing CAML queries, when a great tool such as CamlDesigner exists (http://www.camldesigner.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<And>` tag is in all caps; CAML is case sensitive.  Try this:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="marking" />
            <Value Type="Text">Off-S</Value>
        </Neq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="marking" />
            <Value Type="Text">Off</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

And like MdMazzotti said, use a tool to build your CAML queries.

Answer (score 2):

CAML keywords are case-sensitive, try writing "And" instead of "AND".

Answer (score 0):

I use a caml query tool called U2U Caml query. Its free and easy. http://www.u2u.be/Software

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried :

```
$caml = '<Where><AND><Or><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" />
<Value Type="Text">Off-></Value></Neq><Or><Neq><FieldRef Name="marking" />
<Value Type="Text">Off</Value></Neq></Or></Or></AND></Where>'
```

maybe this helps you